# watir, how can I validate table presence

Tags: validation, watir

I am using watir in RadRails IDE. I need to validate if a table is present on the page. How can I do this? I can't check if some text in the table is present because I could have the same text in another table.

Comment: An example of the HTML would be handy here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You "just" have to have a way to uniquely identify the table. I will assume that the table has `id` attribute.

```
browser.table(:id => "one").present?
# => returns true or false
```

Comment: if ie1.table(:xpath, "//*[@id='flexibleTable']").exists?